# A combinatorial lemma

Tags: combinatorics

The following combinatorial lemma is from Benson's polynomial invariants of finite groups, lemma 1.5.1 used to prove a generalisation of Noether's degree bound.

The polynomial in $n$ variables $x_1x_2\ldots x_n$ satisfies the identity$$
(-1)^nn!x_1x_2\ldots x_n = \sum_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}} (-1)^{|I|}\left( \sum_{i\in I} x_i\right)^n,
$$where $I$ runs over all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

The author did not give a prove of this formula, and I have no idea how to prove this identity since I'm not familiar with combinatorics. Can someone points a reference to me or help me with a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the sum on the right $S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Then $S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$
is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$. But if we set $x_k=0$ we get
\begin{align}
&S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1},0,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n)\\
&=\sum_{J\subseteq\{1,\ldots,k-1,k+1,\ldots,n\}}(-1)^{|J|}\left(\sum_{i\in J}x_i\right)^n
+\sum_{J\subseteq\{1,\ldots,k-1,k+1,\ldots,n\}}(-1)^{|J|+1}\left(\sum_{i\in J}x_i\right)^n=0
.
\end{align}
The first sum here accounts for the $I$ with $k\notin I$ and the
second with $k\in I$.
Therefore $x_k$ is a factor of $S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for each $k$. This
means that $S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a constant multiple
of $x_1\cdots x_n$. But the only term in the sum containing the
monomial $x_1\cdots x_n$ is the one with $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and in this
term the monomial has coefficient $(-1)^nn!$.
Therefore
$$S_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(-1)^nn!x_1\cdots x_n.$$

Comment: Yes, I see ! This makes absolute sense!